# QGIS - How can I combine two rasters on top of each other

Tags: qgis, raster, layers

In QGIS I have 2 rasters, let's call them LowQuality and HighQuality.

I have a large area of LowQuality data, and some HighQuality data which should substitute the LowQuality data in those cells.

In the image below you see the HighQuality data layer (black = NODATA) on top of the LowQuality data layer.

How can I use the HighQuality data in combination with the LowQuality data to get a combined layer of both?

EDIT: I am trying to produce a new layer, which uses the available HighQuality data and fills the rest with the available LowQuality data.

Low Quality data layer:

[image: LowQuality data]

High Quality data layer:

[image: HQ data]

LQ and HQ on top of each other:

[image: LQ and HQ on top of each other]

Comment: If your question related to just displaying the rasters,  set NODATA to transparent in the high quality layer and stack it above the low quality layer. If you're trying to produce a new combined raster use the raster calculator to select the value from the high quality layers if it's not NODATA, otherwise pick the value from the low quality layer.

Comment: @Llaves
Yes, I am trying to produce a new layer.
The data (everything except NODATA) of the HighQuality layer should substitute the data in the cells of the LowQuality data.
Can you give me a hint how to do that?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options in the Processing Toolbox, including Merge, r.patch and Build Virtual Raster.

One key point to note is that the ordering of the selected layers is important, and not consistent from tool to tool. You can drag the layers around in the Input Layers tab to get them in the right order.

[image]

### Merge

For **Merge**, later layers are overlaid on earlier layers. So you need to make sure that the High Quality layer is after the Low Quality layer. You will need to manually set the input and output NoData value. Merge uses gdal_merge behind the scenes.

### r.patch

For **r.patch**, earlier layers are used to "patch" later layers. So you need to make sure that the High Quality layer is before the Low Quality layer. r.patch seems to handle NoData values automatically

### Build Virtual Raster

For **Build Virtual Raster**, similar to **Merge**, later layers are overlaid on earlier layers. So you need to make sure that the High Quality layer is after the Low Quality layer. Build Virtual Raster references the underlying rasters, so handles NoData values automatically. Build Virtual Raster creates a virtual raster (VRT) referencing the original files, rather than a GeoTiff. This can be useful if you expecting to update the underlying data, or annoying if you want all the data in one file.

The output for all options is the same.

**Low Quality**

[image]

**High Quality**

[image]

**Combined**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Merge was the thing i was looking for :) EDIT: unfortunately my rep is too low to upvote your answer... (min 15)